# iOS: Allow user interaction but disable selection of other cells in UICollectionView when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I have implemented a horizontal menu using a collection view. In the situation where I have selected a cell and I scroll through the collectionView, I would like the other cells to not be selectable until the scrolling has ended, while maintaining the selection state of the previously selected cell. Simply setting `allowsSelection = false` will deselect the previously selected cell. I have implemented the following methods to detect for the scrolling to complete:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if collectionView.isScrollEnabled {
        isDragging = true
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

However, setting `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` means that I can't manually prematurely stop the scrolling in the case that I have made a quick swipe, which is not desired. How can I achieve this? Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can achieve this without enabling/disabling user interaction.

1. Make `isDragging` a global variable.

   `var isDragging: Bool = false`
2. Make following changes to `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods:

   ```
   func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.isDragging = true
   }

   func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if !decelerate {
            self.isDragging = true
        }
        else {
            self.isDragging = false
        }
   }

   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.isDragging = false
   }
   ```
3. Add following logic to `UICollectionViewDelegate`'s `didSelectItemAt` method:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !self.isDragging {
            // Your code related to cell selction here.
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, simple and straightforward. Not sure why I didn't think of this before.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped!